# Honeypot protection with Ajax

Tags: ajax, honeypot

Recently i got attacked by nasty auto-form fill bots which filled my shout form with all sorts of spam. My shout form consist from a html file with 2 textboxes,an ajax script(for refreshing without reloading) and my php file for handling all the inserting data into my DB.

I am thinking implementing a hidden textbox for a minimum protection against these bots but with no luck since i cant pass the honeypot data to my php file. My code:

**HTML Form**

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="postdata.php">
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" maxlength="20">   
        <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="message"   maxlength="255"></textarea>   
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Ajax script**

```
$(function(){refresh_shoutbox();$("#submit").click(function(){var a=$("#name").val();var b=$("#message").val();var c="name="+a+"&message="+b;$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"postdata.php",data:c,success:function(d){$("#shout").html(d);$("#message").val("");$("#name").val("")}});return false})});

function refresh_shoutbox(){var a="refresh=1";$.ajax({type:"POST",headers:{"cache-control":"no-cache"},url:"postdata.php",data:a,success:function(b){$("#shout").html(b)}})};
```

**postdata.php file**

```
<?php 
if($_POST['name'] or $_POST['message']) {
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $message= $_POST['message'];
///do other stuff/////
?>
```

I will insert a hidden field in my html form

```
<input id="email" name="emails" style="display:none"></br>
```

but i cant manage to pass the extra value to my existing ajax script.Tried some code but with no luck.
Any help so i can get my shoutbox up and running again?

Comment: Hi, what's wrong with $("#email").val() ? Does it work from the console?

Comment: you mean the ajax function should look like this? $(function(){refresh_shoutbox();$("#submit").click(function(){var a=$("#name").val();var b=$("#message").val();var em=$("#email").val();var c="name="+a+"&message="+b;$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"postdata.php",data:c,success:function(d){$("#shout").html(d);$("#message").val("");$("#name").val("")}});return false})});

Comment: yes. and add `em` to `c` that makes `var c="mail=" + em + "&name="+a+"&message="+b`

Comment: i'll check it and get back2u

Comment: worked like charm.TY!